# Updating to GLIBC 2.34 for use with Matlab

Tags: linux-mint, matlab

I am running Matlab B2021b on a Linux mint machine.

`uname -r`  output:

```
5.14.0-1024-oem
```

I checked my GLIBC version and got this

```
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.7) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

which tells me that I have glib version 2.31 which has a [bug](https://nl.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/2632298).

On the MathWorks website the guy who reported the bug stated 3 solutions.
The first one is to run
`open_system(new_system('abcdef123456')); bdclose('abcdef123456')` in the console before opening a project but this results in the same crash as when running simulink. The second option is to use glib 2.34 or later which is what I am looking for.

Is it possible to update to glib 2.34? Running
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`  does not seem to fix the issue.

I am avoiding the last option because I am fairly certain that I will break my system trying to patch this bug and it is somewhat hard for me to pull off.

I am not sure if the updated 2021a Matlab version is affected and using that version is my last resort

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to upgrade `glibc` or `libc6` to get later features of a more recent release. Attempting to use a different version would render your system unusable.

The latest major release of Mint, which is 20.#, is built off of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS which has 2.31. The LTS favors stability over what is the most recent. It's likely that the next major release of Mint, 21.#, will be built off of Ubuntu 22.# (or 21.#) which both have 2.34.

You'll either have to use Ubuntu 21.# or wait until Mint 21.# is released if you want to use the same family of distributions.

Comment: Any idea when the new Mint 21.# will be released

Comment: A little after Ubuntu 22.04, the next LTS, which is due next month (22.04 means April 2022).